# Two functions under one ng-click button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The thing is i don't want to call them both at the same time like using:

`<button ng-click="startCounter(); stopCounter()" >`

Is there a way to implement this? Here is my code which is using two buttons.

Here is my Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/v3vk3ho0/

Comment: But what do you want to accomplish? A toggle button for start and stop?

Comment: you can place 2 button with start and stop resp. and use ng-show and ng-hide like toggle..

Comment: It is possible. Nothing wrong in <button ng-click="startCounter(); stopCounter()" .

Comment: Don't quite understand what you want, but you can put two statements in ng-click like you did in question.

Comment: I would suggest putting the two functions in a "parent" function to wrap them , in your plnkr you are calling a function named `startStopCounter()`, just declare that function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although your question is not quite clear, since you do not describe what you actually want or expect to happen, i guess you want to alter the calls from click to click. so you want to call the first function when you click the button first, then the second, then the first again, etc.
so here is a solution for that:

```
<button ng-click="_counterMode = !_counterMode; _counterMode ? startCounter() : stopCounter()" >
```

what this does is on every click toggling the helper variable _counterMode (from false to true, from true to false, etc) and depending on its value execute function 1 or function 2

Comment: Frankly speaking this is very ugly solution that highly decrease maintainability and readability

Comment: Thanks! It works as i wanted :) PS: There is lacking _ in third counterMode

Comment: yes of course it is an fast and dirty solution @maurycy
and i wouldn't use it as is in my project. the better solution is to put the code into an external function in your controller - as usual.

Comment: Well, you know you could edit the answer with proper solution. Lots of developers learn from answers and if you know it's dirty you shouldn't post it or karma will give you a legacy project made by a developer like that ;)

Comment: I would create a function called "toggleCounter", and keep the logic in the controller instead.